# ECONNREFUSED Inside of Docker Container; Accessing Remote API

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, axios, phpbb

Recently, I've been building a nodejs bot to run games on a phpbb forum. I have the bot running locally on my machine (logging in, posting, scraping threads, ect.), so, naturally, I've started to dockerize it.

However, even when running through the login workflow from inside of my docker container, I'm receiving `ECONNREFUSED` errors from inside of the container when trying to hit the forum's api. There's no official docs for the aforementioned api, so a lot of this has been self-investigation.

I'm running node v14.4.0 with axios v0.19.2 + toughcookie v4.0.0 for requests. I'm able to successfully curl the endpoint with the same payload from inside of the container, so I suspect there's something that's going over my head with axios/node.js. I've tried to look at other issues with docker and ECONNREFUSED, but most of them on stackoverflow relate to inter-container communication instead of issues with external apis/access.

The container is running as a root user, and I don't have any sort of proxies or wonky networking set up.

Does anyone have any advice or inklings? My docker-compose is pretty bare bones, but I've included it below for reference.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  bot:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

Any tips or theories would be much appreciated; I've hit the end of my list!

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried starting your node app using the `sudo` command prepended to your server start command?...It might be that your app has no permissions to run a functionality in the implementation of you end-point

Comment: I'm running as root inside of the container, and explicitly running my build and start steps with `sudo` still throws `ECONNREFUSED`. :(

Comment: The port command works the other way around, it exposes a port on the container to the host.

Comment: I'm exposing that port since I'm building an API around this too. :) Your comment below about using the host network did the trick though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you try to reach the host from the container. A simple way of accomplishing this is to use host networking instead of container networking. Try

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  network_mode: host
  bot:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
```

A better way is probably to put the rest of your application in container as well and use the service discovery in Compose, e.g.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  bot:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
  webapp:
    ...
```

Then you can reach the PHP app by connecting to the host name "webapp" in the above example.

Comment: Adding `network_mode: host` did the trick. I haven't run into this before when hitting external APIs with docker, so it's a good thing to know!

Thank you!